# How to write "on duplicate key update" for Laravel 5.2 eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table, it's unique key is `app_id + channel_id` but it doesn't have primary key.

I want to use `on duplicated key update` statement to insert/update a `last_update_time` field in `Laravel` eloquent model, I found `updateOrCreate` method but it's not recognized in my project, how should I write my model?

Comment: please check this   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 4):

`` DB::statement("INSERT INTO `table_name`(`col_name_1`, `col_name_2`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name_1= VALUES (col_name_1)", [val_1, val_2]); ``

Laravel allows for raw database statements with `DB::statment($query, $bindings = [])`.

One thing to make sure of, the second argument must be an indexed array and not an associative. If it is associative it will throw a general SQL exception.

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel Documentation (see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) last part)
There are two methods in Laravel:

Other Creation Methods

There are two other methods you may use to create models by mass assigning attributes: firstOrCreate and firstOrNew. The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the given attributes.

The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it:

```
// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...

$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);

// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...

$flight = App\Flight::firstOrNew(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Comment: But why I cannot use this method? like `firstOrCreate`, I'm just a model extends ` Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])`?

As long as you use a table that has an auto-increment `id` column, you can use your `Model::updateOrCreate()` with the first argument as an associative array consisting of the attributes you are looking for, and the second argument as an associative array with any new values.

See the method definition for [updateOrCreate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L269).