# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I just started laravel and all I want to do is get **following query** working **in Eloquent**:

```
INSERT INTO geschichte (geschichte_id, 
                        geschichte_text1, 
                        geschichte_text2, 
                        geschichte_text3) 
VALUES (:geschichte_id, 
        :geschichte_text1, 
        :geschichte_text2, 
        :geschichte_text3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE geschichte_id = :geschichte_id, 
       geschichte_text1 = :geschichte_text1, 
       geschichte_text2 = :geschichte_text2, 
       geschichte_text3 = :geschichte_text3;
```

**Controller function**

```
public function alterGeschichte(Request $request)
{
    $geschichte1 = new Geschichte;
    $geschichte2 = new Geschichte;
    $geschichte3 = new Geschichte;

    $geschichte1 = Geschichte::updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => 1],
       ['geschichte_text1' => $request->geschichte_text1]
    );
    $geschichte2 = Geschichte::updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => 2],
       ['geschichte_text2' => $request->geschichte_text2]
    );
    $geschichte3 = Geschichte::updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => 3],
       ['geschichte_text3' => $request->geschichte_text3]
    );

    $geschichte1->save();
    $geschichte2->save();
    $geschichte3->save();

    return redirect('/geschichte');
}
```

**The problem in more detail**
I cannot get the 'on duplicate key update' part to work.
 
There always is a new entry created for every time I update. I would like the id always to be the same for every entry and just overwrite the older entry with that id.
I would be very thankful for any kind of help. I am struggling with this from hours...

**UPDATE**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGeschichteTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('geschichte', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('geschichte_text1');
            $table->text('geschichte_text2');
            $table->text('geschichte_text3');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('geschichte');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the CREATE-Table statement. Is the id set as primary key and do you have other primary keys in the table ?

Comment: @XzenTorXz I updated the question. The id is the only primary key.

Comment: Why do you make new models before updateOrCreate?

Comment: @chasenyc I thought I have to do that. If that is not necessary, I will leave that out!?

Comment: if thats the case, how does the mysql table data looks like, do you actually have multiple rows with `id = 1` ?

Comment: There is one row with id = 1. And when I enter something new an entry with id = 2 is created. However, I would like the entry with id = 1 to be overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of what is in your controller should not be necessary. I am also a little concerned about the database structure you are using as to why you would perform a task like shown in your controller. The following should be all you need:

```
public function alterGeschichte(Request $request)
{
    Geschichte::updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => 1],
       ['id' => 1, 'geschichte_text1' => $request->geschichte_text1]
    );

    Geschichte::updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => 2],
       ['id' => 2, 'geschichte_text2' => $request->geschichte_text2]
    );

    Geschichte::updateOrCreate(
       ['id' => 3],
       ['id' => 3, 'geschichte_text3' => $request->geschichte_text3]
    );

    return redirect('/geschichte');
}
```

If these are creating new records it is most likely because there is no record with those ID's.

Comment: You already helped me tremendously. However, there is still a new id created for every entry. Although I would like id 1 always be id 1. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: I've edited my post to have what should work; however, you should really be asking yourself if you should be identifying them by ID. It would be much better to use a different column besides ID to update your table.

Comment: updateOrCreate does not do `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, which can cause some people issues.

Answer (score 10):

Since Laravel 8 there is `upsert` method that mimics SQL `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` functionality.

This query builder example:

```
DB::table('flights')->upsert(
    [
        ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
    ], 
    ['departure', 'destination'], 
    ['price']
);
```

is equal to the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO flights (departure, destination, price) 
    VALUES ('Chicago', 'New York', 150)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = 150;
```

The `upsert` method has 3 arguments.

1. Values to insert or update
2. Column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table
3. Array of columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database

The columns in the second argument MUST have a "primary" or "unique" index.

[Full documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#upserts)

Comment: what is the returned value then. I expected it to be the id like insertAndGetId but is something else the affected rows

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you don't have a unique key setup on the columns you wish to be unique.  In order to use `on duplicate key update`, you will need that so your database server will know if it needs to insert or update.

Unfortunately, Laravel doesn't have support for `on duplicate key update` syntax.  This would be useful because it tries to insert and if it's already in the table, then it will update the columns accordingly in one query.

Using Laravel's `updateOrCreate` method, it first queries the table to see if it needs to generate an insert or update statement and then proceeds accordingly.  You don't get the advantage of running just one query but at the same time, it's Laravel which is handling all the extra logic so it's a slight trade-off.

Comment: Someone suggested a raw workaround for DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Laravel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52782637/470749

Answer (score 2):

updateOrCreate not work like ON DUPLICATE UPDATE you can use upsert

```
    $data = [
        'user_id' => $id,
        'profile' => $profile
];
use DB::table('tablename')->upsert($data, ['user_id'], ['profile']);
```

user_id: column must have unique index

Comment: `upsert` is indeed compiled to a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` with MySQL!

Comment: Note, `upsert` is only available since Laravel 8.x