# Laravel mysql query for multiple insert with condition for unique constraint (using query builder)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, insert

My mysql query is as follows :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1 ,col2)
            VALUES (val11 ,val12),(val21 ,val22),(val31 ,val32)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3=VALUES(col3);
```

Normal multiple insert I am able to do.

But how to add this condition (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3=VALUES(col3)) ?

How can I write this piece of code in LARAVEL. I am new in Laravel so please show some way.

Update:

Why my question is different? because , I want to code in Query builder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308555/on-duplicate-key-update-in-eloquent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308555/on-duplicate-key-update-in-eloquent)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention , I need to do it in Query Builder. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Query Builder, it would be [updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert)

```
DB::table('mytable')->updateOrInsert(
    ['col3' => 'col3'],
    ['col1' => 'val11', 'col2' => 'val12']
);
```

Comment: I am having the data to inserted in multidimentional array like this: 
[
  0 => [
    "col1" => "val11"
    "col2" => "val12"
  ]
  1 => [
    "col1" => "val21"
    "col2" => "val22"
  ]
]
How can I pass this data ?

Comment: You could try `array_values(Your Array)` within the function

Answer (score 1):

Use updateOrCreate ..

```
$sample= App\SampleModel::updateOrCreate(['col3'=>'val3'],['col1' => 'val1', 'col2' => 'val2']);
```