# PHP Laravel import and update product list with unique key

Tags: php, laravel, import, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

I'm writing CSV importer to add/update product list in DB. Product list should have stable ids, so it's important to update records, not to delete and add new ones. Also product feed may have duplicate product lines, I need only oldest date record for particular product (field "import_key" controls that).

Model Product have fields:

```
id          - incremental integer, which is DB primary key
merchant_id - merchant id
pid         - product id in merchant database (unique for particular merchant, not unique globally)
// Ten other properties here
import_key  - date field.
```

pid+merchant_id is unique key

```
    Product::whereMerchantId(self::MERCHANT_ID)
      ->update(['import_key' => NULL]);

    $csv_data = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $curl_result));
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        $product=new Product();
        $product->merchant_id = self::MERCHANT_ID;
        $product->pid=$data[1];
        $product->name=$data[2];
        // Ten properties assigned here
        $product->import_key=$data[13];

        $old_product = Product::whereMerchantId(self::MERCHANT_ID)
          ->wherePid($product->pid)->first(); // unique key test

        if ($old_product === null) {
            $product->save();  // I have new merchant+pid
        } else {
            if ($old_product->import_key==NULL || $old_product->import_key>$product->import_key) {
                // updating old record or we have found older date record in file for this product
                $old_product->name=$product->name;
                // Ten properties assigned here
                $old_product->import_key=$product->import_key;
                $old_product->update();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that in code I have 10 assign lines (which is ok) and 10 update lines, which I'd like to avoid. I tried this, without success (no error, but record is not updated in DB).

```
    if ($old_product->import_key==NULL || $old_product->import_key>$product->import_key) {
        $product->id=$old_product->id;
        $product->update();
    }
```

If I use `$product->save()` instead update then "Duplicate key" SQL error is returned (naturally).
Please advise for more elegant solution.

**EDIT**: I have got a suggestion of another similar question. In that answer is stated, that

> Unfortunately, Laravel doesn't have support for on duplicate key update syntax.

Yet I'd be ok with other methods to avoid code duplication in my marked `// Ten properties assigned here` places, as I'm still following golden "no copy-paste rule" I heard learning Pascal long time ago:

> If Your program have places where you need copy-paste your own code - something is wrong with Your program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308555/on-duplicate-key-update-in-eloquent)

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz, sorry, but I think it's not duplicate question. I added my opinion to question.